# how do arrange for a uitableviewcell to launch another datepicker view to select the date?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

how do arrange for a uitableviewcell to launch another datepicker view to select the date?

So I want one of my tableviewcell's to be displaying a date, but if the user wants to edit the date they click on this cell (in the tableview) and it will pop another view up with a date picker.  After the user picks a date from this separate view they come back to the table view and the cell will be updated with the date picked.

For example:  would it be something like:

- create a separate XIB/controller view that just has a date selector on it
- in your tableview controller have it so that when that specific cell is clicked, it pops a new view onto the navigation stack (that being the date selector view)
- then in the date selector view have a delegate to pass the value back to the tableview controller, so in the tableview controller you'd need to implement that delegate to catch the response
- then you would update the UILabel in the cell with the value that came back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea: embed the UITableView and DatePicker on the same UIView in interfacebuilder.  Initially set the size of the UITableView to its container, so DatePicker is pushed out of visible area.  When user touches a cell, change the coordinates of the UITableView and datepicker such that UITableView shrinks and datepicker slides up. You can animate this transition using UIAnimation.  After the date has been picked, you can do the opposite animation and set the cell appropriately.

Comment: interesting Yasser - I would never had thought of that - I'll leave the question open longer however - I was hoping for some help doing a more standard approach like somehow trigger from the button push to launch another controller (maybe via the navigation stack) and then coming back.

Comment: We actually used this technique for one of our projects.  Launching a new controller is definitely an option also but having just a date control on a page is unwieldy in my opinion.